How can I get the data-id from a button when clicked and then add that value to the splide.go() function?
I have an image carousel created using the splide carousel and Hubspot Hubl fields.
The image carousel rotates between photos as it should but I want to make it so when a user clicks on a primary button (from the loop) that it will get the data-id being assigned to it (ex: 1 or 2) and then push that value into the splide.go(); function (which tells the splide carousel which image to show). I will use these buttons so users can click a button labeled whatever and it corresponds to an image in the splide carousel and will show it.
I think the issue is the .forEach loop I've set up. I've also tried a for loop but wasn't sure which was best for this situation. When I mess around in the console I see that the attribut value being logged is either undefined or one value like a "4" no matter which button I click. I'm missing something or have the syntax wrong which only provides the value for the button clicked.
Any help is appreciated.
I have code below but it won't work because it uses Hubl but the main thing I'm asking for a look at is the 2nd javascript section where the loop is. If I add a number to the splide.go() it works how I want so something isn't capturing the data-id from the button clicked from my code in the way it's set up
To clarify- I want a loop that for any primary button will pull the data-id assigned to it and then I want to pass it as a variable within the splide.go() function.


  var splide = new Splide( '#features-image-carousel', {
    pagination: true,
    autoplay: true,
    arrows: true,
        navigation:true,
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
  }).mount();


let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.features-top-tab .button-primary');

    buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.onclick = function(e) {
    var attribut = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log(attribut);
                splide.go(absolut);
        
  };


})
.features-tob-tab .button-primary {
align-items: center;
    border-radius: 40px;
    display: flex;
    font-family: Quicksand;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 2px solid var(--Primary-Colors-White, #FFF);
    color: #fff;
    }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<div class="features-top-tab-row">
                {% for item in module.top_carousel_tab %}
                <div class="features-top-tab">
                <div data-id="{{loop.index}}" class="button-primary">
                        {% inline_text field="top_carousel_tab_text" value="{{ item.top_carousel_tab_text }}" %}
                        </div>
                </div>
    
                {% endfor %}
            </div>



I've also tried a for loop:
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.features-top-tab .button-primary');
    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) { 
 var id = this.info;
            button[i].addEventListener ('click', function() {
            splide.go(2);                           


});
             };

    });


To get "data-id" attribute value you can use HTMLElement dataset property. In your case it's something like this:
button.addEventListener ('click', function(event) {
    const id = event.target.dataset.id;
});


Thanks Anna. Is my loop set up properly though? It kept getting just 1 value not individual values, which is where I think I didn't set it up right

The console is logging the unique numbers per buttons but that value isn't going into splide.go() for some reason.

I ended up getting help and this code is what worked: $(document).ready(function(){
var splide = new Splide( '#features-image-carousel', {
pagination: false,
autoplay: false,
arrows: true,
navigation:false,
type: 'loop',
perPage: 1,
}).mount();
$('.features-top-tab .button-primary').click(function() {
let id = $(this).data('id');
console.log(id);
splide.go(id-1);
});
});
